# You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an Ember.Application

Tags: ember.js

i'm getting error with ember 0.9.8.1

```
You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an Ember.Application
```

any idea what this is happening? some suggestions on where i should look into?

thanks.

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509076/ember-js-widgets

Comment: According to this pull request, "It means you are creating multiple Ember.Applications without specifying different rootElements. The default rootElement is body." https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1192

Comment: It really sucks to see an ember question without a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot bind several Ember application to the same DOM element, as it will conflict for DOM maintenance.

You nevertheless can instanciate several Ember applications in the same page. Try something like that:

```js
App1 = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#app1'
});

App1.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App1.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'app1-view'
})

App1.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            path: '/'
        })
    })
});


App2 = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#app2'
});

App2.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App2.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'app2-view'
})

App2.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            path: '/'
        })
    })
});
```

Here, we explicitly set the DOM element to which the app will bind, using `rootElement` property.

By default, an Ember app binds to `body`, so if you have twice, they conflict...

Example @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/FMV8u/13/

Comment: This eliminates the warning message, but in your fiddle, the App2.ApplicationView isn't actually loaded.

Comment: Indeed, I does not work anymore. I take a look at that. Thx for the info.

Comment: I just filled an issue (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1395) as it seems like a regression.

Comment: Fixed! `initialize()` is no more needed. :-)

Comment: changing the version of JQuery to 1.8.3 on JSfiddle will solve the problem as well