# Ember qunit: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element (#ember-testing) multiple times in an Ember.Application

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-cli

This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571896/you-cannot-use-the-same-root-element-body-multiple-times-in-an-ember-applicati), but I do not think it's related, because my problem is the reaction of a bug that should have been fixed within here: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/pull/85

But I still get this error.

The code:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import { test, moduleForComponent } from 'ember-qunit';
import startApp from '../../helpers/start-app';
var App;

moduleForComponent('navigation-sidebar', 'NavigationSidebarComponent', {
    setup: function(){
        App = startApp();
    },

    teardown: function(){
        Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
    }
});

test('it opens sub menus on click', function() {
    expect(3);
    visit('/documents').then(function () {
        ok(find('.parent ul').length, 'Page has submenu.');
        equal(find('.parent ul').is(':visible'), false);
        click('.parent a');
    });


    andThen(function() {
        equal(find('.parent ul').is(':visible'), true);
    });
});
```

I tried various thing on teardown like reset, wrapping destroy in ember run, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

A bonus question: I tried `bower update ember-qunit`, `bower update ember-qunit --force`, deleting the ember-qunit folder and run `bower install git@github.com:rwjblue/ember-qunit.git` - and always ended up with the unpatched version. In the end, i downloaded a zip and pushed it directly into the directory. Why is that not working?

Comment: What ember-cli version are you on?

Comment: 0.0.46, error occured for the first time on 0.0.44

Comment: Could you post the content of your `tests/app/index.html`?

Comment: It's been generated by ember-cli: http://pastebin.com/mfDFUWPD

Comment: After upgrading `ember-cli`, did you follow the steps described here: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.0.46 (re `ember init` ing)

Comment: Well, i did - but the entire process is really tedious and error prone and always makes the entire upgrading process really hard because it tries to overwrite all my configuration and package customization staff. I now did it again and am stuck with `ENOENT, no such file or directory '/frontend/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-qR43Frk3.tmp/config/environment.js'` with a not helping stacktrace.

Comment: I did now manage to apply ember init by doing it file-by-file. However, the original error still applies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62454/discussion-between-lulezi-and-shredding).

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved it:

- `moduleForComponent` is for unit tests only, just use `module` for integration tests
- `import { test } from 'ember-qunit'` broke the test, just remove it.